# Using tag `code` with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I would like to display code in Vue.js using a `<code>` block. But when I display it, the code loses its formating. I googled and found that I should add `<br>` after each line to get it to work. But I can't understand when I should to do it. After user input?

```
Vue.component('view-form', {
    props: ['mycode'],
    template: `
        <div class="ViewCodeContainer">
            <code class="language-dart"> {{mycode}} </code>
        </div>`
})

Vue.component('past-form', {
    template: `<div><textarea placeholder="Your code here..." v-model=mycode></textarea></div>`,
    data () {
        return {
            mycode: ""
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sendClick(e) {
            bus.$emit('codechange', this.mycode);
        }
    }
})

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        currentView: 'past-form',
        mycode: ''
    },
    methods: {
        sendCode() {
            this.currentView = 'view-form';
        }   
    }, 
    created() {         
        bus.$on('codechange', function(mycode) {
            this.mycode = mycode; // filling mycode from user input in HTML
        }.bind(this));
    }
})
```

I would prefer not to use `<pre>` because `<code>` is more semantically correct.

Comment: Are you sure that is vue relative? If yes, can you provide a small code to reproduce?

Comment: You can use `<pre>` instead of `<code>`.

Comment: Have you considered something like [vue-embed](https://github.com/Gomah/vue-embed)?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't want to use `<pre>`, you can still change the way `<code>` is displayed. See the [whitespace property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp). That's a pure CSS solution:

```
code {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```css
code {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<code>code {
  white-space: pre;
}</code>
```